# Symfony2 Assetic and Less Sourcemaps

Tags: php, symfony, less, assetic, source-maps

I am unsure how I can hack the assetic less filter to output a sourcemap file. I am referring to the LessFilter here https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/LessFilter.php

[lines 145 and 146](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/LessFilter.php#L145-L146) is where the `Symfony\Component\Process\Process` object is created

```
  $proc = $pb->getProcess();
  $code = $proc->run();
```

The trouble is this output gets placed into one single file. I am not sure how to generate a second sourcemap file.

How can I extend this filter or hack the Assetic core to make this work?

Comment: I ended up removing Assetic completely from my app. Build tools like Gulp and Grunt allow me to do everything I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the right spot. However, you don't need to hack it. Extend it!

I use this:

```
# Using less source maps with Symfony
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Assetic;

use Assetic\Asset\AssetInterface;

class LessFilter extends AsseticLessFilter
{
    public function filterLoad(AssetInterface $asset)
    {
        $sourcemapRoot = realpath(dirname($asset->getSourceRoot() . '/' . $asset->getSourcePath()));

        $this->addTreeOption('sourceMap', true);
        $this->addTreeOption('sourceMapBasepath', $sourcemapRoot);

        parent::filterLoad($asset);
    }
}


// config.yml
assetic:
    filters:
        less:
            class: Acme\MyBundle\Assetic\LessFilter
```

I found this snipped here:
https://github.com/thomaswelton/blog/blob/master/articles/symfony/using-less-source-maps.md

It extends the Filters' filterLoad() method by adding two new tree parameters. All available tree parameters can be found here:

https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/bin/lessc#L361-L378

You gotta love dependency injection :)

Comment: How can I force creation of `.map` files (required for CSS auto-reload in Chrome DevTools) instead of inline maps. Tried `sourceMapOutputFilename` and `sourceMapFilename` with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Another way I've found to show the origin less file contents without faffing around with paths is to use the outputSourceFiles flag which bundles the less files into the generated css file (adds bloat so use in dev only).

```
<?php
...
class LessFilter extends AsseticLessFilter
{
    public function filterLoad(AssetInterface $asset)
    {
        $this->addTreeOption('sourceMap', true);
        $this->addTreeOption('outputSourceFiles', true);

        parent::filterLoad($asset);
    }
}
```