# symfony2 assetic source maps less

Tags: symfony, assetic, source-maps

I'm using:
- Symfony2
- Assetic(Bundle)
- NodeJs tools for compiling css+js through assetic

My less files are *not* stored in the public-dir (obviously).

I want to use source mapping to be able to edit less/js files in the browser in a dev-environment.

Looking at this question:
[Symfony2 Assetic and Less Sourcemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255882/symfony2-assetic-and-less-sourcemaps)
I've already got mapping information at the bottom of each generated css file.

But both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox fail to load the less files. Probably because they are not in the public dir, but I don't want them there obviously.

How can I configure assetic in such a way I can open+edit+save the less files in my browser?
This should preferably link directly to disk, as I would want to commit those files to git later.

Additional question:
* Is it possible to generate a separate map-file? Since I read that Google Chrome prefers this for reloading when something changes.